# Erro de dateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Estou pegando uma data de dois dateTimes diferente e concatenando em uma variável só, porém quando vou escrever o conteúdo dessa variável fica da seguinte forma:

Período: System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 20/07/2017 15:52:45 Até System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 20/07/2017 15:52:45

```
 String dataTime = tempoInicialEXP.Text + " Até " + tempoFinalEXP.Text;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você tem que utilizar a propriedade `Value` do `DateTimePicker`:

Exemplo:

```
tempoInicialEXP.Value.ToString();
tempoInicialEXP.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
tempoInicialEXP.Value.ToShortDateString();
```